# How to change appendix labels?

Tags: hyperref, labels, appendix

I have the following latex code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
      
\usepackage{latexsym}% Package loading the LaTeX symbol.
\usepackage[center,tight,small]{subfigure} 
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false,justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[latin1, utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{epstopdf}      
\usepackage{titlesec}  
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{2mm}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}       
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}

\counterwithin*{footnote}{section}
  

% CHANGE SECTION STYLE


\titleformat{\section}
  {\LARGE\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\Large\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}


\addtolength{\skip\footins}{2pc plus 5pt}

%APPENDIX   
% Renumbering equations and figures within the appendix. 
\renewcommand\appendix{\par 
    \setcounter{section}{0}%   
    \setcounter{subsection}{0}%     
    \setcounter{equation}{0} 
    \setcounter{table}{0} 
    \gdef\thefigure{\Alph{section}.\arabic{figure}}%
    \gdef\thetable{\Alph{section}.\arabic{table}}%
    \gdef\thesection{\Alph{section}}%
    \gdef\thesubsection{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}}% 
    %\@addtoreset{equation}{section}%
    \gdef\theequation{\Alph{section}.\arabic{equation}}%
}

\def\appendixname{Appendix}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{CommentColor}{rgb}{0.953,0.371,0.258}
\definecolor{LinkColor}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.5}
\definecolor{RefColor}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.5} 

\usepackage{xr-hyper}  
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pdfstartview=FitH,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref} %option dvipdfm for dvi
\usepackage{atbegshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}


%PDF Farben einstellen
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,%
    linkcolor=RefColor,%  
    citecolor=LinkColor,% 
    filecolor=LinkColor,%
    menucolor=LinkColor,%  
    urlcolor=LinkColor
} 

\let\orgautoref\autoref
\providecommand{\Autoref}{%
    \def\equationautorefname{Equation}%  
    \def\figureautorefname{Figure}%
    \def\subfigureautorefname{Figure}%
    \orgautoref}
% \autoref is used inside the sentence
\renewcommand{\autoref}{%
    \def\figureautorefname{Figure}%
    \def\tableautorefname{Table}%
    \def\sectionautorefname{Section}% 
    \def\subsectionautorefname{Section}%
    \def\appendixrefname{Appendix}%
    %\def\propositionrefname{Proposition}%
    %\def\theoremrefname{Proposition}%
    \orgautoref} 
\newcommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname} % subfloat

\newcommand{\bc}{\color{CommentColor}}  
\newcommand{\ac}{\color{black}}

\begin{document}

    \title{\bf \LARGE{Title}\\ 
\Large{Title 2}}
    
    \author{Rollo99$^*$ \\
(\small{University})}\thanks{Email: \url{ciao@hotmail.it}.}

        \date{(September 2021)}  
    \maketitle   
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}} 
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}} \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \setcounter{page}{1}\pagenumbering{Roman}
    
    
    \vspace{-10mm}
     
    
    %\newpage


    \begin{abstract}   
        \singlespacing
        Abstract
    \end{abstract}    
     

    \newpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}\pagenumbering{arabic}
     
    
\section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}


Introduction. Then I want to refer to \autoref{sec: app}.

Need to fix it because now I see displayed \autoref{sec: app_a} and \autoref{sec: app_a0} and \autoref{sec: app_a1} 

\newpage

\appendix

\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\section*{APPENDIX}\label{sec: app}


This Appendix is organised as follows.

\section{Ciao 0}\label{sec: app_a}
   
Ciao ciao ciao

\subsection{Ciao 1} \label{sec: app_a0}

The aim of this paragraph is to .....

\subsection{Ciao 2} \label{sec: app_a1}

Ciao ciao ciao


\end{document}
```

The issue is that now it is displayed: Section 1, Section A.1 and Section A.2 (see below):

[image]

I would like to see displayed instead: Appendix, Appendix A.1, Appendix A.2, etc.

Can anyone help me do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The level of automation and complexity required to update `\autoref` and content written to the ToC so that hyperlinks are automatically updated with an `Appendix` prefix, together with the deviation from referring to an appendix *without* the sectional number probably outweighs the ease of using internal, manual hyperlinking via `\hyperref[<link>]{<stuff>}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
      
%APPENDIX   
% Renumbering equations and figures within the appendix. 
\renewcommand\appendix{\par 
  \setcounter{section}{0}%   
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%     
  \setcounter{equation}{0} 
  \setcounter{table}{0} 
  \gdef\thefigure{\Alph{section}.\arabic{figure}}%
  \gdef\thetable{\Alph{section}.\arabic{table}}%
  \gdef\thesection{\Alph{section}}%
  \gdef\thesubsection{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}}% 
  %\@addtoreset{equation}{section}%
  \gdef\theequation{\Alph{section}.\arabic{equation}}%
}

\def\appendixname{Appendix}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{CommentColor}{rgb}{0.953,0.371,0.258}
\definecolor{LinkColor}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.5}
\definecolor{RefColor}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.5} 

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pdfstartview=FitH,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref} %option dvipdfm for dvi

%PDF Farben einstellen
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,%
  linkcolor=RefColor,%  
  citecolor=LinkColor,% 
  filecolor=LinkColor,%
  menucolor=LinkColor,%  
  urlcolor=LinkColor
} 

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Introduction. Then I want to refer to the \hyperref[sec:app]{Appendix}.

Need to fix it because now I see displayed \hyperref[sec:app_a]{Appendix~\ref*{sec:app_a}} and 
  \hyperref[sec:app_a0]{Appendix~\ref*{sec:app_a0}} and 
  \hyperref[sec:app_a1]{Appendix~\ref*{sec:app_a1}}.

\newpage

\appendix

\section*{APPENDIX}\label{sec:app}

This Appendix is organised as follows.

\section{Ciao 0}\label{sec:app_a}
   
The aim of this paragraph is to \ldots

\subsection{Ciao 1} \label{sec:app_a0}

The aim of this paragraph is to \ldots

\subsection{Ciao 2} \label{sec:app_a1}

The aim of this paragraph is to \ldots

\end{document}
```

You can build up the hyperlink string using starred versions of `\ref` (`Appendix~\ref*{<label>}`). If you only have a handful of references, then this surely is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider adding below at the beginning of your appendix:

```
% %% ==========================================================
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}

\appendix

\setcounter{figure}{0} \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{table}{0} \renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
\setcounter{algorithm}{0} \renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{algorithm}}
```

Comment: How would this change the `\autoref` behaviour?